# Selection bar with a ruler using Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to make a ruler in Qt. I am developing an application which requires a line edit in which the user can select any part of the string. When the selection is done, the start and end co-ordinates of the selection are passed to the backend.

The ruler which is shown with the line edit has a precision of one character or blank space in the string.
I have built a similar widget using Java and ExtJS some time ago. I am trying to simulate the same with Qt for quite some time now but not succeeding in doing so.

Please take a look at the image to understand what it looks like. I want to know whether it is possible or not in Qt. If it is possible what widget should I use to achieve it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure I understand your question correctly. 
You can write a class inheriting from `QLineEdit` to emit signals when its selection has changed.

Below is a simple example of such a class: it takes the native signal `selectionChanged` and has two new signals which emit information about the changed text just to show what could be possible. I also include a simple dialog class to show how to use this (even if it's just a crude way).

**lineedit.h**

```
#ifndef MYLINEEDIT_H
#define MYLINEEDIT_H

#include <QLineEdit>

class LineEdit: public QLineEdit
{
  Q_OBJECT

    public:
  LineEdit(QWidget *parent = 0): QLineEdit(parent)
  {
    connect(this, SIGNAL(selectionChanged()), this, SLOT(textSelectionChanged() ));
  }

  public slots:
  void textSelectionChanged() {
    emit selectionChanged(this->selectedText());
    emit selectionChanged(this->selectionStart(), this->selectedText().length() );
  }

  signals:

  void selectionChanged(const QString&);
  void selectionChanged(int , int );

};

#endif
```

**dialog.h**

```
#ifndef MYDIALOG_H
#define MYDIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QtCore>

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
  Q_OBJECT

    public:
  Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0) : QDialog(parent) {}

  public slots:
  void textChanged(const QString &string) {
    qDebug() << string;
  }

  void textChanged(int start, int length) {
    qDebug() << "Start"<< start << ", length: " << length;
  }

};

#endif
```

**main.cc** (for completeness)

```
#include <QApplication>

#include "dialog.h"
#include "lineedit.h"
#include <QHBoxLayout>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  Dialog dialog;

  QHBoxLayout *layout = new QHBoxLayout(&dialog);
  LineEdit lineedit;

  layout->addWidget(&lineedit);

  QObject::connect(&lineedit,SIGNAL(selectionChanged(QString)), &dialog, SLOT(textChanged(QString)));
  QObject::connect(&lineedit,SIGNAL(selectionChanged(int,int)), &dialog, SLOT(textChanged(int,int)));


  dialog.show();

  return app.exec();

}
```

Let me know if this helps.